# Standard Windows error dialogs

Tags: winapi

How can I display a standard error dialog on Windows, independent of the OS language, such as the following?

> The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

(as used by Notepad etc.) PowerISO (which has a multilingual interface) will always display this message in the OS language (Dutch in my case).

For example, when using `ofstream` in C++:

```
bool write_file(const char* filename)
{
    ofstream f(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!f.is_open()) return 0;
    // (...)
    return 1;
}
```

And then in some Windows message handler:

```
if (!write_file("recipe.txt"))
{
    // MessageBox("The process cannot ..." ??
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Win32 API [`FormatMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to translate Win32 error codes into localized text strings.  For example:

```
if (!write_file("recipe.txt"))
{
    DWORD dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
    LPTSTR lpMsg = NULL;
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, dwErrorCode, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPTSTR)&lpMsg, 0, NULL);
    MessageBox(..., lpMsg, ...)
    LocalFree(lpMsg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there had to be something!!

Answer (score 2):

You're probably going to have to translate the string into other languages yourself. I don't think Windows is going to give you a built-in database of localized standard dialog strings. If you are willing to translate them yourself, you can use a [string table](https://www.google.com/#q=windows+string+table+tutorial) to load the string for the appropriate language based on locale.

Comment: @Midas I know, but I don't think Windows has a convenient lookup table (or API function) for these that you could use, even for strings that it obviously does use itself. I can't say definitively there's not a way, but I've never heard of it and couldn't find anything in a couple minutes of searching.

Comment: There is a localized lookup function in the API - `FormatMessage()`